Permittivity as only a function of conductivity?
I am having trouble with understanding the relationship between the conductivity and permittivity.
When I take Ampere's law in differential form and take its gradient, I get the continuity equation:
$ \nabla \cdot J =  -j\omega\cdot \rho$
If I replace $\rho$ with $\rho=\epsilon_0\epsilon_r(w)\nabla E$ and remove the gradient from each side, and replace the current density with $J = \sigma E$ I get:
$\sigma(\omega) = -j\omega\cdot\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r(\omega)$
This would lead to the conductivity being directly proportional to the permittivity. I know however, that they should be related with the complex permittivity:
$^c\epsilon_r(\omega)=\epsilon_r(\omega)+j\frac{\sigma(\omega)}{\omega\epsilon_0}$
What am I doing wrong?

It seems like you missed something about the definition of sigma, because it must be real number for it to be valid in the last equation. Is it not? Check this out: https://physics.byu.edu/faculty/colton/docs/phy442-summer21/lecture-10-complex-wave-number-index-of-refraction-and-relative-permittivity.pdf
